# vba that selects only numbers or only text

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for vba that will select and copy only numbers or text from a specific range based on which ever one I choose example would be:

```
Column A
xs
s
m
l
xl
1
1.5
2
2.5
3
3.5
```

How would the vba work to select the text (xs,s,m) or the numbers (1,1.5,2) and copy it.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for Range.SpecialCells method. 
You can find documentation from msdn here. 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

```
Range.SpecialCells(type as xlCellType, [Value])
```

Returns a range. So, we could store that range like this.

```
dim rngNumbers as Range
set rngNumbers = ActiveWorksheet.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants,xlNumbers)
```

Then you just have to call the .Copy method.
The subs below should do the trick without the extra object.

```
Sub copyNumbers(source As Range, dest As Range)
    source.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Copy dest
End Sub

Sub copyText(source As Range, dest As Range)
    source.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Copy dest
End Sub

Sub main()
    dim sourceRange as Range
    Set sourceRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

    copyNumbers sourceRange, ws.Range("D1")
    copyText sourceRange, ws.Range("E1")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Go To Special** for that. If you need the VBA for it I suggest you record yourself doing this:

[image: 1]

Select the options you want:
[image: 2]